# Spring MVC Redirecting http instead of https

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to redirect to TAM logout url when user clicks on *logout*.. But its returning `http url` instead of `https`.. I am making call using `https` only.. but the redirect somehow getting the info of `http` and `port`.. and transferring to that..

```
public class TAMJunctionLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    private static final String TAM_LOGOUT_DEFAULT_URL = "abclogout";

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication )
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        String redirectUrl = getDomainRoot( ( HttpServletRequest ) request );
        redirectUrl = redirectUrl + TAM_LOGOUT_DEFAULT_URL;
        ( ( HttpServletResponse ) response ).sendRedirect( redirectUrl );
    }

    private String getDomainRoot( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        String serverPort = "";

        // Do not append default ports
        if ( request.getServerPort( ) != 80 || request.getServerPort( ) != 443 ) {
            // append the port
            serverPort = ":" + request.getServerPort( );
        }
        return request.getScheme( ) + "://" + request.getServerName( ) + serverPort + "/";
    }
}
```

Comment: set  property <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" /> in viewResolver

Comment: Thanks Nilesh.. By adding the redirect info in tomcat will worked